# excel macros and vba code for rows iteration

Tags: vba

I have a set of 30 rows which fits the A4 page exactly. I would like to add rows in between and I donot want to disturb that 30 number count which exactly fits in A4 page. Can anyone help me with it? Is it possible to make the rows exceeding after 30 to move to next column?

Comment: not exactly. but thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can insert page break after every 30 rows.

Put this code behind the worksheet that you are trying to insert the page break.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

   Dim LastRow As Long
   Dim RowIndex As Long
   Dim RowNo As Long

   'No. of rows between each page break
   RowNo = 30

   With ActiveSheet
       'Remove all existing page breaks
       .ResetAllPageBreaks

       'Get the last row with data in col A
       LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

       For RowIndex = RowNo + 1 To LastRow Step RowNo
           .HPageBreaks.Add Before:=.Cells(RowIndex, 1)
       Next
   End With


End Sub
```